# How can I create a KafkaConsumer during runtime? (In Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am working on an application that already consumes and creates Kafka messages. Creating Listeners that are initialized at startup using @Component and consume whatever messages are send to their respective topic(s) is not an issue.

But for the import of a big number of entries into a database, I have to wait for a REST-call before I start to consume certain Kafka topics and filter for a specific search pattern provided by the REST-call. How can this be achived?

My idea was to do something like this:

```
public ResponseEntity<Result> restCall(String searchCriteria){
  ...
  MyKafkaListener mkl = new MyKafkaListener(searchCriteria);
  // Do whatever I need to do to get it running...
  mkl.start();
  ...
}
```

I only found a very complex way using KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry and a bunch of factory classes that need implementing. Do I really have to implement all those interfaces to do what I plan or is there a simpler way to start Kafka consumers as needed?

EDIT:

One idea was to have a class that I could configure while it's already instanziated. My Listener could be like

```
@KafkaListener(id = "myListener", topics = { "wholeLottaTopics"}, autoStartup = "false", groupId = "${spring.kafka.groupid}")
    public boolean onMessage(ConsumerRecord cr)
    {...}
```

This Listener would be initialized during startup and I could get access to it and start it:

```
MessageListenerContainer myListener = kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myListener");
myListener.start();
```

But retrieving it this way, I cannot access it's fields like searchCriteria etc. Also, when I get multiple REST-requests that tell my service to import data from the same topics according to different criteria, I cannot run another Consumer at the same time.

Comment: Please give more details on the expected flow. Do you really need to create a new consumer dynamically? Or do you need to start consuming messages during runtime but the consumer can be instantiated and initialized at startup? And what about the messages not matching the filter? Can be consumed and thrown away, right?

Comment: You should use a registry. You should start the listeners as stopped. When you get a request, then request the registry to start any listener. Alternatively, don't use Kafka? Just query the database with your filter information

Comment: I have to wait for a certain job outside my realm to have finished, when this happened I will get notified via REST-call. Then I have to read a bunch of Kafka messages, about 1-3 million.

Starting consumers stopped seems to be a possibility. How could that be done? Using Kafka is unavoidable, I won't get access to the source database.

Comment: Kafka consumer provides methods pause() and resume() for this.

Comment: @Mar-Z Yes, but I could get multiple REST-calls for the import of different groups of data. I can create one KafkaConsumer that doesn't start until the first request comes and then retrieve it via something like kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainer("myListener"); - But then I have to tell it what to filter for. Also, what can I do when the next request comes along to consume the same topic but filter for different criteria? 

That's why I thought about dynamically creating new Listeners but have no clue how.

Comment: What do you mean exactly with filtering? Do you want to consume only particular subset of messages from the topic? Leaving the rest untouched for future processing? I'm not aware of such functionality in Kafka. I know it like this: consume a message, if it match the filter then process it, otherwise throw away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with the following solution, it's not exaclty what I need and will need some work, but this basically does what I need:

ConsumerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class ConsumerConfig {
    @Value("${spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers}")
    String bootstrapAddress;
    // Import all the other settings from application.yaml using @Value-notation

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        // Create props for Factory
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrapAddress);
        // ...

        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }
}
```

Then, inside of my REST-Controller:

RestController.java

```
public class RestController{
    @Autowired
    ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory;
    // ...
    private void consumeKafka(String searchCriteria) {
        Consumer<String, String> consumer = consumerFactory.createConsumer();
        consumer.subscribe(Arrays.asList("a.bunch.of.topics"));
        while(true){
            ConsumerRecords<String, String> consumerRecords = consumer.poll(Duration.ofMillis(100));
            for (ConsumerRecord cr : consumerRecords) {
                // Convert cr to object, check whether object fits criteria, import or not...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This basically does the trick and can be invoked in parallel, but leaves my microservice with a bunch of open and never gracefully deserializing KafkaConsumers.

Thanks to @Mar-Z and @OneCricketeer for your input!